# File can not be loaded from src/test/resources while working on spring boot junit tests

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I created one folder src/test/resources and added one file Test.json and trying to access in junit test like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ReadController.class, secure = false)
public class ReadControllerTest {

    @Value("${classpath:Test.json}")
    Resource testFile;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{


        File file = testFile.getFile();
        System.out.println(file.exists());

    }   
}
```

When I run this unit test, it tries to find file in classpath but file is not present there.
How to add this file in classpath?

Comment: try File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(this.getClass().getResource("/some_file.txt")); to read the json file in test/resources folder

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It worked for me. can you share the code which you tried with my suggestion. Please don't forget to mention "/" at the beginning of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

By Default, spring boot classpath will be pointed to src/main/resources but you are using src/test/resources.
Try to copy the JSON file to src/main/resources.